# O usuário pode alterar cores do aplicativo já compilado?

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou pensando em criar um app em que o usuário pode alterar as suas cores do Layout como quiser com cores pré definidas, mas não consigo pensar em uma forma de fazer isso, se é que é possível. Alguém tem algo conhece algo parecido?

Comment: Seja mais específico. Quer mudar a cor do quê exatamente? Você tem uma tela com um componente específico que precisa mudar de cor? Se sim, coloque o código dela aqui (e do XML).

Comment: Você deve estar procurando por alterar dados do XML em tempo de execução. Acho q esse tópico deve te ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/160924/alterar-programaticamente-a-cor-de-fundo-do-menu-overflow-na-toolbar De uma olhada e me fala se é isso mesmo.

Comment: Quero mudar as cores da barra de statatus e dos drawables que estão sendo usandos para estilizar botões, como exemplo do aplicativo Twitter, tem dois temas, um deixa todo o app claro e outro escuro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei uma forma fácil.

Criei um arquivo res/values/attrs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="drawable_color" format="reference" />
    <attr name="background_color" format="reference"/>
    <attr name="font_color_1" format="reference" />
    <attr name="font_color_2" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

E no arquivo res/values/styles.xml adicionei o seguinte código:

```
<style name="RedTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorDkRed2</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorDkRed1</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorBlack1</item>
    <item name="drawable_color">@color/colorDkRed2</item>
</style>
```

Onde eu posso definir a cor que quiser para este atributo que sera aplicada ao item do drawable.